# Variable mapping in IDA hotkey change

Tags: ida, ida-plugin

Is there a way to change hotkey for variable mapping ('=' by default)? For example: I'd like to bind it to 'Shift+Q'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please have a look at the second part of this [blog post](http://www.hexblog.com/?p=437).

You can either manipulate your `shortcuts.cfg` or use the `Options->Shortcuts` GUI since version 6.2.